# Anybody knows an specific procedure for solving this excercise?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, moment-problem

I'm new here. If I break any rule, please, tell me and I will fix it immediately.

Well, long story short. Due to COVID-19, I had some financial troubles and I coudln't keep up paying my internet service for a couple of weeks. I'm currently studying Software Engineering and I missed a lot of Online classes with literally no way to get in touch with my teacher.

I had some assignments which, I've been struggling solving them, but gladly, I'm currently in the last assignment until now. I need to solve 50 exercises, but I really missed the base for solving them, If someone could help me out with the first one, I'll be incredibly thankful and I'm sure it'll help me out with the topic, here's the problem:

"Calculate moments about the X and Y-axis. Calculate the mass and center of mass. Consider $\rho = x + y$"

Functions: $g(x)=-x-10 / f(x)=-x^2+2x$

On the bottom says: Use fractions, don't leave blanks spaces between signs and numbers, for example, $-151/7$

My teacher just uploaded this example to the class feed, but he won't be able to support us. I can't really relate it to the kind of problems in the assignment...

This is the first assignment problem:
[image: Here you can see the image.]

This is the example:
[image]

Comment: What do mass and momentum mean in this context?

Comment: I'm really sorry, It got automatically corrected, It is moment, not momentum.

Comment: That’s okay, but how can mass be related to a function?

Comment: I have the same doubt... I already emailed my teacher, hope he answers soon, thanks for replying to my question! I'll update with his reponse as soon as he answers.

Comment: Alright, so, he says he won't just re-do the whole class just because I wasn't present (understandable), he told me that the only thing he could do was giving me an example, I'll add it to the main question in a second.

Answer (score 0):

I may be mis-reading, but I don't think the question is set up correctly.  Let's just look at the mass.  The mass should be the double integral of the density over the given region:

$$m = \int_{-2}^5 \int_{-x-10}^{-x^2+2x} \rho \; dy \; dx.$$

Since $\rho$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, it needs to be inside the integral.  And when you're done integrating, $\rho$ won't appear in the answer.  But the blanks for the answers have $\rho$ next to them.   This would be the format if $\rho$ were constant (that is, if you had uniform density.)

So it looks like your instructor set up the problem as if it were a uniform density problem, and then gave you a non-uniform density.  You might gently ask him if he's attempted to answer the question himself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying! I'll ask him.

Comment: Hey man, just wondering. Looking at the example, where it says: "Hallamos a y b" (We find a & b). Can you identify how does he comes with the results: a = -2 & b= 3?

Comment: It's the intersection points of the curves $y=x-3$ and $y=x^2-9$.